# Why do my components only show on resizing the window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i need to make a chessboard look in jpanel with a gridlayout and jlabels. So that works fine as for now. But my Main Window only shows the components on resizing.

The question is, how do i get my JPanel to use the size of the label tiles and then the Jframe to use the size of my JPanel?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow(){
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addNewGameArea();
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addNewGameArea(){

        GameArea game = new GameArea();
        this.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
public class GameArea extends JPanel {

     public GameArea(){
        super();
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
        addLabels();            
        //this.setPreferredSize(this.getPrefferedSize());
        this.setVisible(true);


    }

    //Creates a 2D JLabel array
    private JLabel[][] createLabel(){

        JLabel[][] labelarray= new JLabel[10][10];
        for (int i=0;i < 10;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                labelarray[i][j] = new JLabel();
            }
        }
        return labelarray;
    }

    // Color the labels alternating black and white
    private void colorLabels(JLabel[][] labelAr){

        //Here i set the color of the tiles, set them opaque and set the size to (50, 50)
    }

    // add the labels to the Panel
    private void addLabels(){
        JLabel[][] labels = createLabel();
        colorLabels(labels);

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                this.add(labels[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my main i just create a new MainWindow.

PS: When i set a specific size for MainWindow like (500, 500) everything shows. But i want it to fit the child components automatically.

Edit: on the launch it looks like this:

[Application launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmNu1.png)

Edit: main

```
public class StartGui {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: The example seems to work okay for me, maybe also provide the `main` method

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43469917/edit) your question to include updated code; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).